# Prevent BindingSource from adding two blank rows to gridview

Tags: c#, winforms, bindingsource

I have BindingSource that attached to grid control like this

```
 private BindingSource listDepartmentDto = new();
 private async Task LoadDataAsync()
{
    listDepartmentDto.DataSource = await departmentService.GetAllDepartmentsAsync();
    gridControl1.DataSource = listDepartmentDto;
}
```

And I binding Controls like this

```
 private void BindingControls()
{        
    var departmentDto = listDepartmentDto.Current as DepartmentDto;
    txtID.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("EditValue", listDepartmentDto, nameof(departmentDto.IdDepartment)));
    txtTitle.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("EditValue", listDepartmentDto, nameof(departmentDto.NameDepartment)));
    txtDescription.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("EditValue", listDepartmentDto, nameof(departmentDto.DescriptionDepartment)));
}
```

And I use CurrentChanged event like this

```
listDepartmentDto.CurrentChanged += new EventHandler(listDepartmentDtoChanged);
private void listDepartmentDtoChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    var departmentDto = listDepartmentDto.Current as DepartmentDto;
    if (departmentDto.IdDepartment == 0)
    {
        btnSave.Text = Resources.Save;

        btnNew.Enabled = false;
        btnDelete.Enabled = false;

        txtTitle.Focus();
        return;
    }
    btnSave.Text = Resources.Edit;
    btnNew.Enabled = true;
    btnDelete.Enabled = true;
}
```

And in btnNew click event like this

```
private async void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listDepartmentDto.AddNew();       
    await Permission();
}
```

The problem is when I click on btnNew  it create blank row and when I select an other row and click again on btnNew  it create new blank row and so on.
How can I prevent this behavior? and if the user move to an other row without entry any data the row removed automatically
The grid view edtiable has set to false.
the grid view (add,remove) row has set to false.
[image: Department Winform]

Comment: If the grid is UN-editable by the user… then what is the purpose of adding a “new empty” row to the grid?

Comment: What type of control are you using? Can you post the XAML?

Comment: Not sure what kind of setup you have there, but you need to validate a Row before it's committed. If it doesn't pass validation, call the `CancelEdit` method and the `AddNew` action is rolled back (i.e., treat it as a Transaction). -- As mentioned, specify what kind of Controls you're working with.

Comment: @JohnG I add listDepartmentDto.AddNew(); to clear text boxes because the text boxes it's Binding to the listDepartmentDto as I show in method BindingControls()

Comment: @JohnV I use Devexpress winform (gridControl ,textedit)

Comment: @Jimi I entry data through text boxes so this scenario of validating row does not meet my needs

Comment: I have added image to my winform

Comment: Since you allow Users to add data using TextBoxes, then this is the exact scenario where validation is not just needed, it's mandatory. WinForms's Controls generates validation events automatically; this is the default behavior. If an User doesn't fill the data as required, roll back the new entry by calling `CancelEdit`. This is also the default behavior.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you so much it's works like a charm. Can you please put it in the answer section?